# How to convert a wildcard pattern to regex in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Wildcard patterns are file system standards that match any characters to a ( ? ) and any sequence characters to an ( * ).

I am trying to use the erlang [re:replace/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-3) function to replace:

a)  `*` into `.*`

b)  `?` into `.`

c)  `.` into `\.`

d)  if a wildcard pattern does not start in a wildcard, then add a `^` (start-match in regex) to the end of the pattern

e)  if a wildcard pattern does not end in a wildcard, then add a `$` (end-match in regex) to the end of the pattern

Somehow I am unable to get the re:replace to achieve this.

Examples:

trying to replace based on item a) above

```
re:replace("something*.log","\*","\.\*").
exception error: bad argument
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which cases does your regexp work / not work for?

Comment: sure. I forgot to report on what I tried. Editing the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confident in the completeness of your spec, you can write the conversion directly (I guess there is no performance problem because regular expression are generally short list)

```
-module(rep).
-compile([export_all]).

replace(L) when is_list(L) -> lists:reverse(replace(L,wildcard(hd(L)))).

% take care of the first character
replace(L,W={true,_}) -> replace(L,W,[]);
replace(L,W={false,_}) -> replace(L,W,[$^]).

% take care of the last character
replace([_],{true,R},Res) -> R ++ Res;
replace([_],{false,R},Res) -> [$$|R] ++ Res;
% middle characters
replace([_|Q],{_,R},Res) -> replace(Q,wildcard(hd(Q)),R++Res).

wildcard($*) -> {true,[$*,$.]};
wildcard($?) -> {true,[$.]};
wildcard($.) -> {true,[$.,$\\]};
wildcard(C) -> {false,[C]}.
```

with your example:

```
11> rep:replace("something*.log").
"^something.*\\.log$"
```

Note that the \\ is one single character as you can verify with:

```
12> length(rep:replace("something*.log")).
18
```

Comment: outstanding. works like a charm. very interesting erlanghish style approach !

Answer (score 0):

In your `re:replace` call:

```
re:replace("something*.log","\*","\.\*").
```

the backslashes don't actually end up in the strings, since they just escape the following characters.  Some backslash escapes have special meanings, such as `"\n"` meaning a newline, but the ones that don't only let the character through unchanged:

```
4> "\*".
"*"
```

So you need a double backslash for the backslash to actually be part of the string:

```
5> re:replace("something*.log","\\*","\.\*").
[<<"something">>,<<".*">>|<<".log">>]
```

Note that the backslashes in `"\.\*"` are not needed.

The return value above is an iolist, which is usually perfectly useful (in particular if you want to write the result to a file or a socket), but sometimes you may want a plain string at additional memory and CPU cost.  You can pass a fourth argument to `re:replace`:

```
7> re:replace("something*.log","\\*","\.\*", [{return, list}]).   
"something.*.log"
```

Comment: super clear. thanks for highlighting the slash issue. lesson learned. thanks